# Maple like collect command in Mathematica

Tags: algebraic-manipulation, maple

In Maple I often simplify expressions for functions of same argument using the collect command:

```
> collect(a*f(x)+f(y)+x*f(x), f, factor)
(a+x)*f(x)+f(y)
```

where the extra option factor will factor the coefficients.

In contrast Mathematica:

```
> Collect[a*f[x] + f[y] + x*f[x], f]
a f[x] + x f[x] + f[y]
```

Is there some command in Mathematica which achieves the same?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to use a pattern in `Collect` which will match the terms you are trying to collect. In this case we want to collect terms like `f[x]` and `f[y]` so a suitable pattern is `_f` which matches any expression with head `f`:

```
Collect[a*f[x] + f[y] + x*f[x], _f]
(* (a + x) f[x] + f[y] *)
```

Comment: Is there also a way to act a routine on the coefficients of the collected terms, like the factor in the Maple command?

Comment: @highsciguy, `Collect` takes a third argument which is a function to be applied to each coefficient.

Comment: @SimonWoods I wonder is there is any general explanation so one don't have to try in each case for collect. I mean, `Head` of `Derivative[1, 2][w][r,t]` is `Derivative[1, 2][w]` but `Derivative[__][w]` is not enough for `Collect` and one has to do `Collect[b D[w[r, t], r] + a D[w[r, t], r], Derivative[__][w][r, t]]`